# “He’s too put off by my illness”?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This extraction taken from the subtitle of the movie “the best offer”.

> - He’s too put off by my illness, like everyone else.

What is the meaning of the sentence?

Answer (score 2):

If you're [**put off**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/put-sb-off-sth-sb) by something, you are repelled or disgusted by it to the point that you don't want to be near it. So, your sentence can be paraphrased like this: he is repelled by my illness just like everyone else is. In other words, my illness must be so repulsive that he, just like other people who come into close contact with me, tries to avoid my presence.

Comment: I'd disagree slightly - in context, I wouldn't say it's necessarily repulsion. I'd interpret it more as: "He's too [also] put off [discouraged] by my illness...", rather than your take on it: "He's too [extremely] put off [disgusted] by my illness...",

Comment: I agree. Connotationally, the meaning does lie somewhere between repulsion and discouragement.